# Edit files from GeneratedJava Folder in Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

One of the new features that came with Android Studio 3.2.1 is the folder generatedJava being highlighted.

I have found out that the classes you can find here are all the classes the project will be built from, including the libraries.

Does that mean I get more access to change those libraries now?
And is it possible to do edit any class/library from there, or what's the point of making those files visible in the new update?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually edit them, but when they will be regenerated, all your edits will be lost.

If you open one such file, Android Studio will show the message:

> Files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be
>   edited.

[image]

And if you try to edit it anyway, the message changes to:

> Generated source files should not be edited. The changes will be lost when sources are regenerated.

[image]